# All sequences as substrings

Tags: code-golf, sequence, subsequence, open-ended-function

Make a program that outputs a sequence of integers so that every finite sequence of positive integers is a substring (continuous subsequence) of the output.

For example, the following sequence satisfies the rules:

`1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,3,2,1,1,3,1,4,...`

To see the underlying pattern, let's format the sequence a bit differently:

```
1,
1,1, 2,
1,1,1, 1,2, 2,1, 3,
1,1,1,1, 1,1,2, 1,2,1, 1,3, 2,1,1, 2,2, 3,1, 4,
1,1,1,1,1, 1,1,1,2, 1,1,2,1, 1,1,3, 1,2,1,1, 1,2,2, 1,3,1, 1,4, 2,1,1,1, 2,1,2, 2,2,1, 2,3, 3,1,1, 3,2, 4,1, 5
...
```

Here you can see that every row contains every sequence of positive numbers that sum to the index of the row. For example, row 3 has all sequences whose sum is 3. This means that every sequence is included somewhere in the list.

Standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) rules apply. As stated before, your sequence may also contain 0 or negative numbers. These non-positive numbers are not ignored, meaning that your output must contain arbitrarily long substrings of only positive integers.

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
∞Ó˜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8w5NPz/n/HwA)

Outputs the exponents of numbers' prime factorization, flattened. It can be easily seen that all sequences will appear - a sequence \$ a_i \$ will appear when we go over the number \$ \prod {p_i}^{a_i} \$ (\$ p_i \$ is the i-th prime)

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 39 bytes

```hs
do y<-[1..];q<-mapM id$[1..y]<$[1..y];q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P902JV@h0kY32lBPL9a60EY3N7HAVyEzRQUkUBlrA6WtC//nJmbm2RYUZeaVqJQkZqcqGBoAgYKKQvp/AA)

Start with the positive integers `[1..]`.  Draw an integer `y`.  Then take the cartesian product of `y` copies of `[1..y]`.  This is just all the ways to choose `y` numbers less than or equal to `y`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
Þ∞ƛṄvṖ;f
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnuKInsab4bmEduG5ljtmIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Pretty much the sequence in the question, but with a lot more 1s. Outputs as an infinite lazy list.

```
  ƛ   ;  # Over each element of...
Þ∞       # 1...∞
   Ṅ     # Get integer partitions
    vṖ   # Get all permutations
       f # Flatten the result
```

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 22 bytes

```r
repeat cat(rpois(9,9))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxRCE5sUSjqCA/s1jDUsdSU/P/fwA)

Outputs a random sequence of integers (realizations of the Poisson(9) distribution). They are printed in batches of 9, including some 0s (which is allowed by OP).

There is a theoretical guarantee that any finite sequence will almost surely be printed eventually.

Comment: Nice, and inspired me to a similar sneaky approach in Husk.  By the way, do you really mean "almost" in "almost surely"...?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen "[Almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely)" means "with probability 1".

Comment: I didn't know that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```javascript
for(x=0n;y=++x;)for(b=1n;y/=b;)console.log(y%++b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/Lb9Io8LWIM@60lZbu8JaE8RPsjUE8vVtk6w1k/PzivNzUvVy8tM1KlW1tZM0//8HAA)

Shortened by @l4m2.

This outputs the mixed-radix digital expansion of each positive integer *n*, where the radices used are 2, 3, 4, ...  Any finite sequence of positive (or even nonnegative) integers will occur in the digits of some *n*.

Comment: [49](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/Lb9Io8LWIM@60lZbu8JaE8RPsjUE8vVtk6w1k/PzivNzUvVy8tM1KlW1tZM0//8HAA)?

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 54 bytes

```
j=k=t=2
while t:=k%2>0!=print(t)or-~t:k=k//2or(j:=-~j)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwU3z_IKizLwSWzDJlZKapgBmaVRoWnEp5EPZWoY6xakFtkoKSjqpeSkgWnNpaUmarsVNsyzbbNsSWyOu8ozMnFSFEivbbFUjOwNFiHkaJZr5Rbp1JVbZttn6-kb5RRpZVra6dVlQ3QugFJQGAA)

This version consistently outputs `True` for `1`.

#### Old [Python](https://www.python.org), 57 bytes

```
j=k=1
while[print(t:=len(f"{k&-k:b}"))]:k=k>>t or(j:=-~j)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3LbNss20NucozMnNSowuKMvNKNEqsbHNS8zTSlKqz1XSzrZJqlTQ1Y62ybbPt7EoU8os0sqxsdeuyNCEGQM2BmQcA)

#### Old [Python](https://www.python.org), 63 bytes (@pxeger)

```
j=k=1
while 1:j+=k<1;k=k or j;t=len(f"{k&-k:b}");k>>=t;print(t)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY37bNss20NucozMnNSFQytsrRts20MrbNtsxXyixSyrEtsc1LzNNKUqrPVdLOtkmqVNK2z7exsS6wLijLzSjRKNCHGQE2DmQoA)

##### Old [Python](https://www.python.org), 73 bytes

```
def f(j=1,k=1):
 while 1:j+=k<1;k=k or j;t=len(f"{k&-k:b}");k>>=t;yield t
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5BCsIwEEX3PcWQhSSYQLOTxiluPYbSxCZT0lAiUsWTuOlG7-RtrFS3n8d7__FKY277OE3Pc3Zq89431oHjAbUk1KIq4NL6zoKuwhppqw0hQT9AMBk7G7ljN1opqo53JgzVNWYzets1kH_CnZtpLwP4CFef-HCIJ8t1WQrpuPgGANLgY-YzJG1skIFSwESxrGLx_A9-AA)

This goes through all positive integers and outputs for each the sequence of distances between `1`s in its binary representation.

For example:

```
1616 -> 11001010000 -> 5,2,3,1
```

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 53 bytes

```
j=k=t=1
while k:=k//t or(j:=j+(t:=1)):print(k%t);t+=1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwU3T_IKizLwSWzDJlZKapgBmaVRoWnEp5EPZOsWpBbZKCko6qXkpIFpzaWlJmq7FTdMs22zbEltDrvKMzJxUhWwr22x9_RKF_CKNLCvbLG2NEitbQ01NK4gp2aolmtYl2raGEM0LoBSUBgA)

Port of @Polichinelle's JS [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242773/107561).

Comment: [63 bytes as a full program](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY37bNss20NucozMnNSFQytsrRts20MrbNtsxXyixSyrEtsc1LzNNKUqrPVdLOtkmqVNK2z7exsS6wLijLzSjRKNCHGQE2DmQoA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞Åœ€€œ˜
```

Outputs the infinite example sequence, but without an unquify of the permutations.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8w61HJz9qWgNERyefnvP/PwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
∞        # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 Åœ      # Map each to a list of all possible lists of positive integers that sum
         # to that integer:
         #  [[[1]], [[1,1],[2]], [[1,1,1],[1,2],[3]], ...]
   €     # Map over each list:
    €    #  Map over each inner list:
     œ   #   Get all permutations of this list
         #    [[[[1]]], [[[1,1],[1,1]],[[2]]], [[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],[[1,2],[2,1]],[[3]]], ...]
      ˜  # Flatten this list of lists
         #  [1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,3,...]
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 39 bytes

```
for(i=1,oo,[print(p[2])|p<-factor(i)~])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/Py2/SCPT1lAnP18nuqAoM69EoyDaKFazpsBGNy0xuQQkq1kXq/n/PwA)

A port of [@Command Master's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242757/9288).

---

### [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 44 bytes (@Polichinelle)

```
for(i=9,oo,[print(d)|d<-digits(i,log(i)\1)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/Py2/SCPT1lInP18nuqAoM69EI0WzJsVGNyUzPbOkWCNTJyc/XSNTM8ZQM1bz/38A)

---

### [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 47 bytes

```
for(i=9,oo,[print(d)|d<-digits(i,log(i)^.9\1)])
```

When \$i\$ is larger enough, \$b = \lfloor\log(i)^{0.9}\rfloor\$ will satisfy \$b^b < i\$. So the code will print the base-\$b\$ digits of a sequence of more than \$b^b\$ consecutive integers, which will contain all sequences of integers in \$1,\dots,b-1\$ with length \$<b\$.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/Py2/SCPT1lInP18nuqAoM69EI0WzJsVGNyUzPbOkWCNTJyc/XSNTM07PMsZQM1bz/38A)

---

### [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 50 bytes

```
for(i=2,oo,for(j=1,i^i,[print(d)|d<-digits(j,i)]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/Py2/SCPT1kgnP18HxMyyNdTJjMvUiS4oyswr0UjRrEmx0U3JTM8sKdbI0snUjNXU/P8fAA)

Comment: The `^.9` is not necessary in `log(i)^.9\1` (-3 bytes.)